# css positioning differently in different dimensions

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a button within a div. The div parent has position:absolute and is positioned fully to the left in the browser window. The child button has position:fixed, because I want the child button to always be a certain distance from the bottom of the browser window (regardless of the parent div).

What I want is to horizontally center the parent div in the browser window (best way to do that?); however, the child button is then in the wrong x-location, since it should be relative to the div but is fixed. Essentially the x-location for the button should be relative to the parent div, whereas the y location should be relative to the browser window (i.e., fixed).

How can I accomplish this?

http://jsfiddle.net/YfWWH/

```
<body>
      <div class="viewport">
          <button id="t">T</button>
       </div>
</body>

.viewport {
background: white;
height: 1024px;
height: 900px;
width: 768px;
margin: 0em auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

#t{

height: 2.2em;
text-align: center;
background: #CA6161;
border: thin solid #943232;
color: #FFF;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0.3em;
left: 57.7em;
border-bottom: thin solid #FFF;
border-top: thin solid #CFCFCF;
border-left: thin solid #CFCFCF;
border-right: thin solid #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Without code, it is usually hard to guess what the exact problem is, and guessing for answers is usually the only thing anybody can do. If you provide a piece of code of your previous attempts, it will be a lot easier to understand what the exact problem you're having is. That piece of code can even be code that doesn't work at all, because it would still give a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Can you provide samples of the code you're having trouble with? Ideally set up a fiddle to help us test it out.

Comment: added a Fiddle and code

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/YfWWH/8/

Just remove the absolute property from the parent and the left property from the child.

```
.viewport {
background: white;
height: 1024px;
height: 900px;
width: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#t{

height: 2.2em;
text-align: center;
background: #CA6161;
border: thin solid #943232;
color: #FFF;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0.3em;
border-bottom: thin solid #FFF;
border-top: thin solid #CFCFCF;
border-left: thin solid #CFCFCF;
border-right: thin solid #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```